# A comic about a heavenly avenger in leather and with claws, might be called Macabre

Tags: story-identification, comics

Some time ago I read a comic set in modern days or nihilistic future a la cyberpunk. It could be kind of British like 2000AD or Toxic, where a heavenly avenger was depicted. He had an "ancient leather" suit, and I think used claw-like weapons. I suspect he was called Macabre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Konrads was right on both counts; the comic was *[Toxic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toxic!)* and the character was called [Makabre](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/makabre/4005-88720/).

[image: Makabre]

There is very little about it on the web though, I had to look at my old issues to work out who you meant.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there are any scans of the series?

Comment: @Konrads- not that I am aware, sorry.  I expect that there will be some on the more comics oriented sites.

Answer (score 3):

The character indeed was called Makabre. He was an avenging type, called during the series, The Rod of God (spare the rod, spoil the child kind of thinking). He was one of several stories that appeared in the UK magazine Toxic during the early 1990s. I was fortunate enough to find a scan of him on the cover and inside one of the issues.

[image: Toxic #7 featuring Makabre, May 1991]

[image]